# loop running continuously when using keys[pygame.K_SPACE] Python/Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a grade 10 student working on a simple video game project in Python with Pygame. 
When I press the spacebar this code should execute:

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]: 

    shotflag = True

    shotX = shipX+((shipwidth/2)-(shotwidth/2))  

    shotY = shipY - 10
```

The problem is ... it executes continuously until I take my finger off the spacebar. I only want it to execute once.
Is there a better way to do this?  Can I use a spacebar RELEASED event?  So it only fires once?

Thanks in advance. 
Matthew

Comment: You could look for the KEYDOWN event which should only be fired once when the key is pressed

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a keydown event for an specific key.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You should be polling events somewhere in your application? This is where you should handle user input

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Ianin Shelvington's answer, you should be handling events in your main game loop.

More information in the pygame docs :[here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            #TODO
```